# Always Errors in Android Kernel on Debian Sid

Tags: android, compiler-errors, kernel

I need to compile my own android kernel for research. I did excactly the things written down in the developer section and then tried to compile the kernel. 
 But every build i try fails because of some errors.. I thought that when i use a stable version i should compile the kernel without any problem...
Is it possible that my gcc and stuff is too new due I'm using Debian Sid and not as recommended Ubuntu 10.04? The Problem is i only have Debian Servers with LXC, so creating a ubuntu Jail seems possible but i dont want to if i didnt need to.
I allready compiled my own Android-x86 Kernel on a Debian Machine and it worked very well!

I tried to compile 2.4.6_r1, 4.0.1_r1, 4.0.4_r1, 4.0.4_r1.2 in different buildsets (full, crespo) but always got some error in C or Java Files.
I have installed sun-java6-jdk and gcc/g++ Debian 4.6.3-5

edit: first it seems like this problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/UrluVAdRTkU
when i did, it actually builds further but even then errors occured...

Comment: What kind of errors do you receive?

Comment: It seems that you do not have all necessary headers. I build aosp on Ubuntu and it works well. So in your case every error should be considered manually.

Comment: mh but then this means the repo sync hasnt worked out well or i'm missing libs?

Comment: I think repo sync worked well (but sometimes it can be a source of errors), you do not have some important headers and libraries.

Comment: I'm getting errors for example in mesa3d. But all mesa-dev packages are installed... there is no more mesa package i could install...

Comment: it seems i have the same issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/UrluVAdRTkU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that on Debian more then just installing the dependecies is required to successfully build a kernel. The Library Versions and Paths seems to differ from them in Ubuntu so much that its nearly impossible to create a stable build environment in small time.

So I'm switching to Ubuntu 10.04 and since then i can build a kernel without any error.